# How to make twisted bar? (Corkscrew)

Tags: modeling

[image]

With the reference image above. I want to make the bottom part which is twisted. At the top it go upward straight and the bottom part it goes narrow. I tried with the screw modifier but how can i make the top and bottom part. I tired to apply the modifier and extruded but the center point did not works. Any suggestion or help how it works.

[image]

Comment: Now you need to convert your curve to mesh, lower down the resolution of your curve and the steps of your modifier if you don't want a too dense topology. Then you need to model the top and bottom. I'm not sure what you mean with the "center point"

Comment: the other solution, if you want to do everything with curve, is to use a spiral curve, then you can extrude the top and bottom, and scale down the bottom vertex

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't create the top and bottom without applying the *Screw* modifier. If you choose to apply, before applying lower down the *Resolution* of your curve and the *Steps* of your modifier in order to keep a low-poly topology. Then you need to model the top and bottom (with some extrusions).

If you want to work with a curve as much as possible you could create a spiral curve (you need to enable the *Add Curve: Extra Objects* addon, then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Curve > Curve Spirals > Archemedian*), play with the parameters in the *Operator Box* (don't create too many *Steps* if you want to stay low poly):

[image]

Then header menu > *Curve > Set Spline Type > Bezier*:

[image]

Then press <kbd>V</kbd> to change handle type and choose *Automatic*:

[image]

Bevel the curve in the *Object Data panel > Geometry*, keep *Round* selected and increase the *Depth* value:

[image]

At last, extrude the top vertex and the bottom vertex, and in order to reduce the bottom vertex radius, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> or type the radius in the *N* panel:

[image]